# PHP + Web Services

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I'm struggling to get a web service to work which we are using to integrate with a software package from Civica. Unfortunately they have sent us code in visual basic which we don't use here and I'm struggling to "translate" the visual basic into PHP.

So here's the code I have so far:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$client = new SoapClient('https://xxx/cx/WebService/WSTokenService? 
singleWsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

The above works and I can see the functions. It's the next bit I can't get to work:

```
$request_param = array('Password' => 'xxx', 'UserName' => 'yyy');

try
{
 $request = $client ->GetUserWSToken($request_param);
 $result = $request ->GetUserWSTokenResult;
 print_r($result);
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
echo "<P><P>Exception Error!";
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I run the above code I get an error message "Exception Error!GetUserWSToken has service faults". I also get another error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

The visual basic code we've been sent by the package company to use is:

```
Dim tokenClient As New TokenService.WSTokenServiceClient
Dim tokenreq As New TokenService.SecurityTokenRequest
tokenreq.UserName = "usernamehere"
tokenreq.Password = "passwordhere"
Dim token = tokenClient.GetUserWSToken(tokenreq)
```

Does anyone know how to translate the visual basic above into what I need to do for PHP?

Comment: looks like the param for `GetUserWSToken` needs to be a `SecurityTokenRequest` instead of an array.

Comment: Do you have any documentation of the XML the request should contain? It might not be as simple as `<UserName>Foo</UserName><Password>bar</Password>`, and the `TokenService.SecurityTokenRequest` object in their sample library would be creating the rest of the structure automatically. Also, try dumping the whole Exception with `var_dump($e)'`, or `echo $e;` as there may be additional details outside the main message.

Comment: I think Jeff's comment is correct - that the parameter for GetUserWSToken needs to be a SecurityTokenRequest and the username and password are variables within SecurityTokenRequest, however I'm struggling with the syntax to get this right.

Comment: @MarinaVitromanovic That class referenced in the VB implementation is presumably included in a library the supplier gives out, but the thing you need to look at is *the definition of the service itself*. In the end, all this code is for creating an XML request, so if you have the documentation for that, you can ignore the VB sample, and build your PHP based on the XML.

Comment: I've had a look at the definition of the service.  I seem to have to use the 'GetUserWSToken' method with 1 parameter which is to call the 'SecurityTokenRequest' method. The latter method has to have 2 parameters associated with it - username + password. I'm struggling with how to call a method with a parameter which is effectively another method that itself has 2 parameters. The syntax is very confusing.